# Error when installing git-plugin on jenkins

Tags: java, git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, filenotfoundexception

I'm trying to install git-plugin on jenkins.

I've installed all the dependencies that are needed for **git-plugin**.

But I'm still getting the file not found exception.

Please help me solve this error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://archives.jenkins-ci.org/plugins/git/3.6.3/git.hpi
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1872)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(HttpURLConnection.java:2982)
    at java.net.URLConnection.getHeaderFieldLong(URLConnection.java:629)
    at java.net.URLConnection.getContentLengthLong(URLConnection.java:501)
    at java.net.URLConnection.getContentLength(URLConnection.java:485)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:1126)
Caused: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://archives.jenkins-ci.org/plugins/git/3.6.3/git.hpi
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1926)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1921)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1920)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1490)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:1139)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to load http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/git/3.6.3/git.hpi to /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/git.jpi.tmp
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:1146)
Caused: hudson.util.IOException2: Failed to download from http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/git/3.6.3/git.hpi (redirected to: http://archives.jenkins-ci.org/plugins/git/3.6.3/git.hpi)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:1172)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1677)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1874)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1651)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:110)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: If I go here: http://archives.jenkins-ci.org/plugins/git/ I don't see a directory for `3.6.3`. How are you installing it? From Update Center or manually?

Comment: from the update center. I do see an update for git-plugin to version 3.6.3